# How to toggle JavaScript on demand (Chrome browser)

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, javascript, ux, usability

In Chrome, I know how to manage exceptions by pointing my browser to `chrome://settings/content` so as to disable JavaScript on just a few sites. But there's this one site which was coded badly, and a list of social buttons is displayed with JavaScript, and these buttons cover the text so I cannot read it. If I disable JavaScript for the site, however, some of the images pertaining to the news disappear.

So, I want to be able to press a toggle button (even a Chrome plugin would do). Such toggle button is used to enable/disable JavaScript on demand for the displayed page. A cookie can remember the value of the toggle if needed. For this badly coded site, pressing the toggle once would allow me to read the text, and pressing it twice would allow me to view the news images around the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I toggle JavaScript on demand in Chrome?

> Quick Javascript Switcher is a Chrome extension that enable / disable JavaScript on the fly by hostname, and subdomain.

See also [quick-javascript-switcher](https://github.com/maximelebreton/quick-javascript-switcher) for the github repository.

Source [Quick Javascript Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-javascript-switcher/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje?hl=en)